# How does Bifunctor in Haskell work?

Tags: haskell

I was reading 'Category Theory for Programmers' by Bartosz Milewski and got really confused by the implementation of bimap in `Bifunctor` typeclass.

```
class Bifunctor f where
    bimap :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> f a b -> f c d 
    bimap g h = first g . second h
    first :: (a -> c) -> f a b -> f c b
    first g = bimap g id
    second :: (b -> d) -> f a b -> f a d
    second = bimap id
```

This is the definition of the `Bifunctor` typeclass taken directly from the library Control. If `bimap` evaluates to `first` and `second`, which in turn evaluates to `bimap` itself, how is this supposed to end? Could you please explain how the evaluation of `bimap` works? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Haskell type class defines a set of functions (sometimes called *methods*) that belong to the type class. In most cases, specific instances must supply specific implementations of one or more of these.

An instance can implement all methods, or just enough to make the instance work. If an instance doesn't implement all methods, the default implementations are used.

Type classes are typically documented with the minimal implementation required. [This is also true for Bifunctors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html):

```
Minimal complete definition

bimap | first, second
```

This means that an instance *must* implement either `bimap`, or both `first` and `second`. An instance can also implement all three, but that's not required.

The tuple instance, for example, is implemented using `bimap`:

```
instance Bifunctor (,) where
  bimap f g ~(a, b) = (f a, g b)
```

This means that the `first` and `second` implementations are the default implementations you quoted above. They call the instance's `bimap` implementation.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Haskell and didn't know there's this thing called minimal complete definition, now I understand how it works.

Comment: After reading this answer, I am aware of the difference between a class and an instance, then the class definition makes sense to me.